# Run playbook from git repo cloned during playbook execution

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I cannot seem to figure this out from the ansible documentation.

I have a playbook X that I want to reuse in various contexts. Like any good software engineer, I put it in a repo in source control (git). So I want my other playbooks to be able to grab and include it, how do I accomplish that? I could include the repo with X as a subtree, but that's not ideal.

Let's say I have a git repo A that has an ansible playbook X. I also have a git repo B that has an ansible playbook Y. What I want is to during the execution of X, clone B and then run playbook Y. This seems like the kind of thing that should be easy to google, and the fact that it isn't makes me wonder if I'm going about this all wrong.

Here's what I've tried in playbook X:

```
- name: Clone B
      git:
        repo: 'http://{{ git_user }}:{{ git_pass }}@somehost/B.git'
        dest: /tmp/B

- name: Run Y
      include_tasks: /tmp/B/Y.yml
      remote_src: yes
```

Even though I have `remote_src` set to yes it keeps telling me it can't find `/tmp/B/Y.yml` on the Ansible Controller, so it seems to be looking on my local box rather than the remote. Repo B is correctly cloned to `/tmp` on the remote (confirmed via ssh).

Comment: And what makes you think this would ever work? Do you see `remote_src` as a valid parameter to the `include_task` module in [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/include_tasks_module.html)?　・　Also, what is the question here?

Comment: @techraf I thought it might work because the error message was `FAILED! => {"reason": "Unable to retrieve file contents Could not find or access '/tmp/B/Y.yml' on the Ansible Controller. If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}` so I tried setting `remote_src`. As for my question I thought I stated it plainly: in the course of executing one playbook I want to clone a git repo with a second playbook and execute it as well.

Comment: I see. Please file an issue to [Ansible repository on GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues) that the advice in the error message is misleading. It is. It should not be printed for any module.　・　"*I want*" is not a question. It is a statement.

Comment: @techraf [Issue opened](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/45661) also, edited question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can get accomplished through a combination of the `git`, `fetch`, and `include_tasks` modules:

```
- name: Clone B on the remote
  git:
    repo: 'http://{{ git_user }}:{{ git_pass }}@somehost/B.git'
    dest: /tmp/B

# This copies the specified file from the remote to the current dir
- name: Fetch yml from remote
  fetch:
    src: /tmp/B/Y.yml
    dest: ./
    flat: yes

- name: Run Y
  include_tasks: Y.yml
```

Note that `Y.yml` must be a plain list of tasks. Since I also want to be able to run it both standalone and included in the project in repo `A` I put a playbook in it's repo that just includes and runs it.

Also in reference to the misleading error message with my first approach (see the comments on the question), it looks like they've [already patched it](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/45667).

Comment: I have the same case only the difference is i want to import playbook instead of include_task. Is this possible with import_playbook ?

Comment: @sanjesh should be? I'm at a different job and don't use ansible anymore but that should work.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done with Roles. The Ansible docs are pretty robust: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html

Create a `requirements.yml` file in the same directory as your playbook, with contents like this:

```yaml
- src: https://github.com/my-org/my-role.git
  scm: git
  version: main  # or specify a particular tag or branch
  name: a-friendly-name-for-my-role
```

Then, install the role using the `ansible-galaxy` command:

```bash
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

Now in your playbook, you can use the role like so:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - a-friendly-name-for-my-role
```

If the role is in a Git repository, and you haven't downloaded it yet, you would first need to download it using the `ansible-galaxy` command, as shown in the first method, and then you can include it in your playbook using the `roles` directive.

If this is a private repo, you'll have to provide credentials in one way or another. There are a multitude of options. If you have git creds stored locally, it should all just work, if you're lucky.

If you're using Jenkins, I landed on this pattern to inject the username and PAT into the `requirements` file. Note that you'll most likely need to create a Personal Access Token for your existing user, passwords don't seem to work for this mechanism. Also, note the use of single quotes in the shell script, which keeps the sensitive creds vars secret.

1. create the `requirements.yml` file as normal
2. In a `script` block in your pipeline, or more preferably in a loaded `.groovy` file or library:

```java
// install-role.groovy
def req_tmp = 'tmp_requirements.yml'

dir('ansible') {
  // install the role from remote
  withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'mygithubuser', passwordVariable: 'GH_PAT', usernameVariable: 'GH_USER')]) {
    // replace the tokens in the requirements.yml with the env var creds into a temp file
    sh """
    set +x
    sed 's/github.com/$GH_USER:$GH_PAT@github.com/g' requirements.yml > ${req_tmp}
    """

    // install the role, then delete the new unsafe file from the workspace.
    sh "ansible-galaxy install -r ${req_tmp} --roles-path . ; rm -f ${req_tmp}"
  }
```

Then go ahead and run your playbook as normal. Another Jenkins example:

```java
  ansiblePlaybook playbook: 'playbook.yml',
    credentialsId: 'my-private-key',
    disableHostKeyChecking: true,
    inventory: <inventory list>
}
```